# Copy and Pasting Data from Source Excel File to Destination Excel File Removes the Data in the Destination File

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to copy and paste data from one excel file to another using openpyxl. I found this script online, but when I run the script, the data from the source file is appended as I want, but the data in the destination file become blank cells. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#Copying Data from Source File and Pasting in Destination File
#Opening the source excel file
filename ="path_to_file"
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]
  
#Opening the destination excel file 
filename1 ="path_to_file"
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename1)
ws2 = wb2.active
  
#Calculating total number of rows and columns in source excel file
mr = ws1.max_row
mc = ws1.max_column
  
#Copying the cell values from source excel file to destination excel file
for i in range (1, mr + 1):
    for j in range (1, mc + 1):
        #Reading cell value from source excel file
        c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = j)
  
        #Writing the read value to destination excel file
        ws2.cell(row = i, column = j).value = c.value
  
#Saving the destination excel file
wb2.save(str(filename1))
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying "the data from the source file is appended as I want," so the data from 'filename' sheet is being copied to the 'filename1' sheet properly? "but the data in the destination file become blank cells" then the data in the 'filename1' sheet goes blank? After you open the updated workbook the values are there then they go blank?  This code copies the values over the mr, mc range from 'filename' to 'filename1', that part works. I dont understand the blank part, there is nothing in the code that would cause that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.